# Class - D Amplification Problem

Tags: inductor, h-bridge, class-d

I am trying to make some amplifier circuit like Class - D type. Below is the circuit;
[image]

Input is sinusoidal @2500Hz.
I couldn't make gate driver circuit. Thats why i use voltage dependent voltage source which is working fine.

@The H - Bridge, there is some point that i couldn't solve. It has to be sinusoidal output current on the inductor but somehow, it is like below;

[image]
Switching frequency: 500kHz.
H-Bridge, All Mosfets are N-Type

Thank you all

Comment: What does the output voltage look like - use a VCVS connected across the inductor with the output ground referenced.

Comment: You will need to look at some **real** class D amplifier designs and see what is done and understand **why** that is done. You have a purely inductive load, why ? Start with a resistive load and see what happens. Also making it difficult on yourself by only using NMOS, again why ?

Comment: Normal class D amps don't  'add Dead Time '